# Can I conditionally render in EJS based on the existence of a variable?

Tags: ejs

I'm writing the template for a form.  On the GET request to the form, it's supposed to render an empty input field (since it's a "blank" form), but if called from a POST request it's supposed to render into the text input field the (invalid) value which had been entered by the user.

I typed:

```
 <% if (genre) { %>
     <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Fantasy, Poetry, etc." name="name" value="<%= genre.name %>" />

<% } else { %>
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Fantasy, Poetry, etc." name="name" value="" />
        
<% } %>
```

The issue is that when I pull up the page using a GET request, I'm getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: /home/mrd2689a/Documents/the_odin_project/express-locallibrary-tutorial/views/genre_form.ejs:13
    11|     <div class="form-group">
    12|         <label for="name">Genre:</label>
 >> 13|         <% if (genre) { %>
    14|             <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Fantasy, 
    15|             Poetry, etc." name="name" value="<%= genre.name %>" />
    16|         <% } else { %>

genre is not defined
```

Does anybody know in EJS how I can conditionally render based on the existence of a variable?

Comment: nice that u solved it but the problem isn't very well explained imho.  the answer to the title though, is yes, as u can read in ejs.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that if I check for (locals.genre) instead of genre, it works as expected.